# Play Action Actuator not working properly (Blender Game Engine)

Tags: game-engine

I am having difficulties with the execution of an Action Actuator I created.

In the logic of the game I got a planet on a first scene.  I'm supposed to click the planet and that will trigger two things: a second scene that'll show a planet rotating and a Plane that'll be fading out from black to transparent through some keyframes established on its Alpha channel.

This fading color action is executed by having the first planet sending a message to a sensor in the second scene.

The thing is working fine when I play it on the Timeline view but when I start the Game Engine itself it won't work by times and when it randomly does is not showing the fading effect but abruptly dissapearing. Any suggestions?

This is how I settled the sensors for the two actions I'm talking about (changing scene and fading out of the plane):
[image]

This is how I configured the sensor for the plane that fades out:
[image]

Plane is called Entrada, action is called AparecerEntrada

Comment: Does it fade when you are already in the second scene and just send the message?

Comment: @Monster This is how it's supposed to look like, this is on the Timeline View https://youtu.be/n8kY0iJkUr0 but when I play it on the actual Game engine it's not fading but looks like this instead https://youtu.be/vBi-Pgowl0Q

Comment: I'm asking because fading usually has no relation to scene switch. Have you checked that the transparency settings are correct? Here is a link with some instructions: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?261926

Comment: @Monster Thank you so much, now it worked!  What I did differently was using a material with an image texture as the link said instead of using just a material by itself.  I also changed the settings as they suggested.  Thank you so much, once again :)